# Neo4j get nodes which do not have another similarly labelled node in it's path to the ancestor

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a tree-like structure in neo4j and I want to find the first nodes with a specific label which has a path to the ancestor and does not have a node of the same type within that path.

For example:

```
  /  (:Y) <- (a:X)
A <- (:Y) <- (c:X) <- (:Y) <- (d:X) <- (e:X)
  \  (b:X)<- (f:X)
  \  (g:X)
```

In this case 'A' is the ancestor, and I want the nodes a,b,c,g because they have the label 'X' and are not separated from the ancestor by another node with the label 'X'

I started with the query:

```
match (c :X)-[:X*1]->(A) return c
```

but it only returns [b,g] and not [c,g] because there are other labelled nodes between the ancestor and 'X' labelled nodes

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) for this, there are configuration options in some of their [path expander procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) that do exactly what you want.

You'll need to use the labelFilter using the termination operator `/`, which means path expansion will stop at the first node of the given label, and that only nodes of those labels will be returned.

Something like:

```
...
// assume you've already matched to ancester 'a'
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(a, {labelFilter:'/X'}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

That should return the first :X nodes along each path from the starting node.

Answer (score 1):

First, get your ancestor node (I pretend it's going to have a :Ancestor label in this case, you might want to adjust the query to reflect reality).

`MATCH (a:Ancestor)`, then get all connected nodes with :X label for up to 2 levels deep: `MATCH (a)<-[*0..2]-(n:X)` and assure that those n nodes are not connected to other X in between: `WHERE NOT (n)-->(:X)` and return: `RETURN n`.

So the whole cypher query would look like this:
`MATCH (a:Ancestor) MATCH (a)<-[*0..2]-(n:X) WHERE NOT (n)-->(:X) RETURN n`.